# Two full height column layout with sticky footer using pure CSS

Tags: sticky-footer, pure-css

I am struggling which seems to be a rather simple challenge.

I need to design simple layout which requirements are:

- pure CSS (no flex-box, no grid, just CSS - no libraries)
- fixed body/wrapper width (1024px, centered)
- fixed column width
- columns stretched 100% height, even if there is no content
- sticky footer (bottom attached)
- tabels can't be used

I came across a lot of answers here on Stack overflow, but nothing seems to work fully like I want.
Here is the scheme:
[image: scheme of layout]

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up so far:

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #FFF;
}

.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
  width: 1024px;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.header {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #33cc33;
  height: 100px;
}

.col-left {
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
  height: calc(100vh - 174px);
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #ff0066;
}

.col-right {
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
  height: calc(100vh - 174px);
  width: 684px;
  background-color: #0066ff;
}

.footer {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #99ff33;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 1004px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">
    <p>test</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-left">
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-right">
    <p>test</p>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <p>test</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Code on **JSFiddle:**

https://jsfiddle.net/adorek/8kecq9pw/22/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `position: relative` to the parent element of the footer. `position: absolute` needs this as a reference point.